# Mvc URL Data Annotation Limitation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my model I have

```
[Display(Name = "Information URL")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Information Url is required.")]
[Url]
public string INFORMATION_URL { get; set; }
```

when I pass this string to the url textbox from my `create` view,it fails my `model.isvalid`property:

```
https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=barcelona&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Uv31U5mUBamN7AaztIHoAw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=899#imgdii=_
```

when i decrease the length of the url let suppose,

```
https://www.google.com.pk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=s_v1U_WSAZHkapL1grAG#q=barcelona
```

It starts working fine,is it there some limitation on length of `url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep your urls less then 2000 character this would be fine.
Here is what the MSDN says :
Microsoft Internet Explorer has a maximum uniform resource locator (URL) length of 2,083 characters. Internet Explorer also has a maximum path length of 2,048 characters. This limit applies to both POST request and GET request URLs.

You issue might be the use of illegal character:
RFC3986 says:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=. Any other character needs to be encoded with the percent-encoding (%hh). Each part of the URI has further restrictions about what characters need to be represented by an percent-encoded word.

As a last resort: Try to remove the first bracket if you have it in the text box. this will make the URL invalid, since you put the attribute of the action to [url] try to add a message [Url(ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid url")] to see this in action

Here is more about the URL attribute:
[URL attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.urlattribute(v=vs.110))

Comment: the data which i posted back to Db is far less than 2000 chars,but it fails the model valid state,moreover with same characters and by reducing length it validates it.It's little bit confusing!!!

Comment: Have you tried to encode your entry. You might have whitespaces that invalidates the URL.

Comment: no i use the online character counter and i tested it with url having 236 characters,till that it work fine,more than 236 characters,i have not yet tested it...

Comment: At the first line of your question you said this is a controller, is it right or you mean Model. Could you add the htmlhelperView you're using Inside the create view.

Comment: `<div class="row1col">
                            <div class="captcol">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.INFORMATION_URL):<span class="req"></span></div>
                            <div class="ctrlcol">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.INFORMATION_URL, new { @class = "extendedtxtbox" })</div>
                        </div>`

Comment: these brackets are generated by this site,when i click hyperlink,elsewise i used the url without braces